# How to use the Dynamic Data Loading examples in vega on the *url* parameter?

Tags: vega

Dynamic data loading is mentioned in the docs and I am looking for examples actually using it.

There is a bit written on signals, but am specifically looking to send the query to the back end.

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/data/